# Proving $\lim_{x\to1}(x^3+5x^2-2)=4$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove that the limit of $f(x)=x^3+5x^2-2$ when $x\to 1$ is $4$. 
So, I want to show that for any $\epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta_{\epsilon}$ such that for all $x$ that satisfies $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-4|< \epsilon$. 
Thus, $|x^3+5x^2 - 2 - 4|<|x^3+5x^2|<|x^2(x+5)|=x^2|x+5|<x^2|x-1|<\epsilon.$

And we know that $x^2|x-1|<x^2\delta<\epsilon $. As such, for every $\epsilon >0$ the corresponding $\delta$ is $\min\{\epsilon/x^2, \epsilon\}, x\neq0$.

Is it right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to prove all polynomials are continuous? We can do this by proving product of continuous functions is continuous and sum of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Overall good, but there are some technical details. For instance, removing $-2-4$ requires that you already know that the function value is above $-3$.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling This is an exercise in using the definitions on cases where you know the answer so that when you don't know the answer you're better equipped to find it.

Comment: Make sense, I hadn't thought of it that way, although I am a bigger fan of always leaving an interesting excercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I concur with Arthur that your work looks OK minus a few technicalities, but those are rather a big deal in real analysis aren't they? Thus, I would write up your proof as follows:

Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|(x^3+5x^2-2)-4)|<\epsilon$. Now,
$$
|x^3+5x^2-6|=|(x-1)(x^2+6x+6)|=|x-1||x^2+6x+6|.
$$
If $|x-1|<1$, that is, $0<x<2$, then $x^2+6x+6<(2)^2+6(2)+6=22$ and so
$$
|x^3+5x^2-6|=|x-1||x^2+6x+6|<22|x-1|.
$$
So if we take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{22}\right\}$, then $|x-1|<\delta$ implies that
$$
|x^3+5x^2-6|=|x-1||x^2+6x+6|<\frac{\epsilon}{22}\cdot22=\epsilon,
$$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure - if we restrict $|x-1| < C$ then we just plug in $C+1$ in $g(x)=x^2 + 6x +6$ then $\delta = \min\{C, 1/g(C+1)\}$?

Comment: In this case, yes--that was the purpose in making it clear that $x=2$ was being substituted into $x^2+6x+6$. If we had chosen $\delta=2$ instead of $\delta=1$, then we would have had $|x-1|<2\Leftrightarrow x^2+6x+6<(3)^2+6(3)+6$ and so on and so forth. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $0<|x-1|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\left|x^3+5x^2-6\right|&=|x^2+6x+6||x-1|\\\\
&<22|x-1|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-1|<\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{22}\right)$