# In delta-epsilon proofs of the limit, why is $\delta$ sometime set to be a minimum of $1$ and some expression of $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

As an example, suppose I want to prove that the limit of $f(x)=x^3+5x^2-2$ when $x\to 1$ is $4$. A solution given by [Mark Viola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872070/proving-lim-x-to1x35x2-2-4-using-the-epsilon-delta-definition-of) is:

> Note that for $0<|x-1|<1$
>
> $$\begin{align} \left|x^3+5x^2-6\right|&=|x^2+6x+6||x-1|\\\\
>  &<22|x-1|\\\\ &<\epsilon \end{align}$$
>
> whenever $|x-1|<\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{22}\right)$

It is not quite clear to me why the minimum is employed. I understand that setting $\delta \leq 1$ is typically done. Is this because there are no inherent restrictions on $\delta$? Is the minimum $\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{22}\right)$ set so that in case we are left with a $\delta>1$, then we can fall back onto $\frac{\epsilon}{22}$?

If so, this doesn't seem to make sense as $\frac{\epsilon}{22}$ was constructed under the $\delta \leq 1$ condition. Instead, should I read the $\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{22}\right)$ condition as saying "both conditions must hold?"

Comment: **COMMENT:** If you were trying to do the limit of $f(x) = 1/x$ as $x\to 1$, can you see that you would want to use a number explicitly less than $1$ to get started (e.g., assume $|x-1|<1/2$? What happens here if you use $1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 <\delta < \min (1,\frac {\epsilon} {22})$ is equivalent to $0<\delta <1$ **and** $\delta <\frac {\epsilon} {22}$.

It is easy to make $|x^{2}+6x+6||x-1| <\epsilon$ if we have a bound for $|x^{2}+6x+6|$: If $M$ is a bound for this then $|x-1| <\epsilon /M$ would give $|x^{2}+6x+6||x-1| <\epsilon$. To get such a bound we take $\delta <1$ and observe that $|x| \leq |x-1|+1<\delta+1 <2$ if $|x-1| <\delta$. This helps us to get a bound $M$.

Comment: What has always confused me is why it is taken to be necessarily small than $1$. Is this because we know $\delta$ will generally be small and so WLOG we can set the boundary at $1$ so as a way to generate a bound?

Comment: @user321627 Taking $\delta$ less than any fixed positive number is good enough here. For definiteness we often choose $1$.

Comment: @user321627 powers of a number less than one get smaller. This often motivates this choice, especially when working with polynomials.

Comment: Thanks, I am still unclear how $\min (1,\frac {\epsilon} {22})$ is equivalent to $0<\delta <1$ and $\delta <\frac {\epsilon} {22}$. Is this a general property or one that is so from how the problem was set up?

Comment: @user321627. Can you see that $\delta=\min(1, c\epsilon)$ implies $\delta \leq 1$ and $\delta \leq c\epsilon$?

Comment: @user321627: It's a general property. If $a \lt \min( b, c)$ then $a \lt b$ and also $a \lt c$. If that's not clear to you just break it down into the 3 cases where $b \lt c$, $b = c$, or $b \gt c$. If you look at where $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be on a number line in each case it should be clear -- you just need to get used to what that translates into using algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The $1$ comes from

> Note that for $0<|x-1|<1$ ...

If we ever allowed $\delta$ to be greater than $1,$ then the inequality
$0<|x-1|<\delta$ would not guarantee that $0<|x-1|<1$, and therefore we would
not be able to use any of the conclusions that followed "for $0<|x-1|<1$".